# Overriding Foundation settings not working in Middleman

Tags: ruby, sass, sprockets, middleman

Im doing my web in Middleman (static Ruby web generator)

I have Foundation installed and working. Then in my styleshhets folder I have a _settings file where I should override foundation's settings.

But somehow it is not working...

My structure is this:

```
web
 source
  bower_components
   foundation
    components
     _settings.scss
   ...
  images
  javascript
  layouts
  stylesheets
   ...
   _settings.scss
   ...
```

Then In the `_settings.scss` on the stlesheets folder I want to override for example the body font color to red like this:

```
// We use these to control various global styles
// $body-bg: $white;

 $body-font-color: red;
```

But is taking no effect.

Config.rb:

```
# Change Compass configuration
 compass_config do |config|
  config.output_style = :compact
  config.add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"
  config.http_path = "/"
  config.css_dir = "stylesheets"
  config.sass_dir = "stylesheets"
  config.images_dir = "images"
  config.javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
 end

 after_configuration do
  @bower_config = JSON.parse(IO.read("#{root}/.bowerrc"))
  sprockets.append_path File.join "#{root}", @bower_config["directory"]
end
```

Any ideas what i need to do to be able to override foundations styles via my _settings.scss on my stylesheets folder ?

Here is my web on github if you need to see the whole structure :

**https://github.com/GiorgioMartini/Giorgio-Web**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `_settings.scss` is imported BEFORE `foundation.scss` it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Your config.rb is correct. However, one thing to pay attention to is the line

```css
@import 'foundation';
```

which will be treated differently than the line

```css
@import 'foundation.scss';
```

Compass will first look to see if there is a foundation.scss file in the bower_components/foundation path. Since there is, it will use that one. Further, since all SASS variables have already resolved in foundation.css, importing _settings.scss beforehand will not change the default styles. Instead, make sure the top of your app.scss file looks like this:

```css
@import 'foundation.scss';
@import 'settings';
```

Because bower_components/foundation/_settings.scss is fully commented out by default, it won't disrupt the new styles.

Comment: No, `@import 'foundation';` will only import either foundation.sass, foundation.scss, _foundation.sass, or _foundation.scss.  Under no circumstance will it ever import foundation.css because 1, no extension was used and 2, even if an extension was used it would be a CSS import.  Also, importing settings *after* youve imported the files that rely on them is counterproductive.